# How can I restrict access to Piwik using NGINX basic authentication and still allow access to the OptOut feature?

Tags: nginx, matomo

Dear NGINX (and Piwik) experts,

I strive to lock a complete Piwik installation with basic_auth (under HTTPS, of course). However, I certainly need to allow public access to Piwiks opt-out feature, which is available unter https://piwik.example.com/index.php?module=CoreAdminHome&action=optOut&language=de and usually embedded as an iframe in other pages (e.g. privacy statements).

The configuration that I consider valid (i.e. it should work according to the documentation, IMHO) is shown below. However, I still get the auth-basic password prompt when accessing the deep link to the opt-out page.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/piwik;

    index index.php index.html;

    server_name piwik.example.com;

    location ^~ /index.php?module=CoreAdminHome&action=optOut&language=de {
        auth_basic off;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted access!";
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd/credentials;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        auth_basic "Restricted access!";
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd/credentials;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe this workaround helps: https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/6448#issuecomment-93688979